# How to be notified of UICollectionView frame changes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios8, uicollectionviewlayout

**The question:**
How can I be notified when the frame of my `UICollectionView` changes so that I may run some code when this occurs? However, I wonder if that is the best solution to the problem.

**The problem:**
I have created my own `UICollectionViewLayout` which needs to know the collection view's frame size before laying out the cells. The problem is, the collection view does not appear on screen (yet) when I set its `collectionViewLayout` property to my custom layout in `viewDidLoad`. So when the layout code is run, the value it obtains for the `collectionView.frame.size` is the width and height defined in Interface Builder, which changes when the collection view appears on screen due to Autolayout constraints. This results in the custom layout returning an incorrect size in the function `collectionViewContentSize`.

**The current solution:**
To work around the problem, I don't change the `collectionViewLayout` until `viewDidAppear`. This does result in the obtaining the correct size. However, this is not done until after the collection view has been displayed with the default Flow layout, so all of the cells have been rendered in a different layout and then I change the layout and cause the cells to be re-rendered. While this is barely noticeable because it occurs so quickly, it's obviously not a good solution.

**The better questions:**
Is it possible to be notified when the size of a `UICollectionView` frame changes? If so, perhaps I could set the layout when that occurs which should occur soon enough to prevent displaying the cells with the default Flow layout.

If that's not possible, a seemingly poor but slightly better solution could be to not display any cells until after the new layout is set in `viewDidAppear`. This would prevent the Flow layout from rendering, but would show a blank UI for a brief moment.

Another option would be to pass in a `CGSize` to the layout class instead of just accessing the `collectionView.frame.size`, and in doing so I could still set the custom layout in `viewDidLoad` and prevent displaying cells in Flow layout. This would require some way of knowing what the collection view size will be before it is rendered on screen which may not be possible (or at least not accurate).

*What would be the best approach to solving this problem?*

Note that I don't need to worry about future collection view size changes, as the layout will be invalided and re-rendered upon bounds change.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called 4 times, the first time it's called the frame is the size set in Interface Builder, the second it's 0 x 0, and the third and fourth calls have the correct values. Perhaps that will be ok, I could compare the values to those in IB and only set the layout when appropriate. I will try that, but perhaps there's an even better solution.

Comment: @SylvainGuillopé Feel free to add this as an answer, it's working well for me if I implement a comparison of the size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) instead as it's called before `viewDidAppear:` so there is a chance that you can get the right frame values at that point.

Note from the documentation:

> However, this method being called does not indicate that the
>   individual layouts of the view’s subviews have been adjusted.